# Unable to resolve "qr-code-styling" from App.js

Tags: android, react-native, qr-code

I have installed qr-code-styling package from yarn via `yarn add qr-code-styling --save` in my react native project, but when I try to reload my react native (expo managed template), an error `unable to resolve "qr-code-styling" from App.js` is thrown.

When I manually inspect node-modules folder, I really see the package.

I have tried to use the same code as used in sandbox but nothing works:

```
qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
 width: 300,
 height: 300,
 image:
   "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Facebook_f_logo_%282019%29.svg",
 dotsOptions: {
   color: "#4267b2",
   type: "rounded"
 },
 imageOptions: {
   crossOrigin: "anonymous",
   margin: 20
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I could resolve it by using the below import statement:

`import * as QRCodeStyling from "qr-code-styling/lib/qr-code-styling";`